# XSL Model : Add Filter on

Tags: xml, xslt

I use this beautiful XSL Model that allow me, among other things, to shorten a value in the `<FLAG>` element.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>

    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ZBE14_OEMs_ItemUpdate_OUT/Record/ItemMaster/FLAG">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
        <xsl:value-of select="substring(normalize-space(), 1, 19)"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I use this Model to import a lot of XML files into a Access files, and it works perfectly.
What I want is to import only the XML that start with "ABC" on the `<FLAG>` element.

Here's an example of the XML I use :

```
<ZBE14_OEMs_ItemUpdate_OUT>
<Record>
    <ItemMaster>
    <FLAG>ABC</FLAG>
    <CONO>700</CONO>
    <WHLO>25H</WHLO>
    <STAT>40 / ZS STAT=20</STAT>
    <ITNO>P167124 / ZS ITNO=MJ63-51</ITNO>
    <SPE3>1A001A / ZS SPE3=</SPE3>
    <FRE3> / ZS FRE3=</FRE3>
    <UNNN>0 / ZS UNNN=</UNNN>
    <HAC1> / ZS HAC1=</HAC1>
    <HAC2> / ZS HAC2=</HAC2>
    <ITGR>AQAAAA / ZS ITGR=AQAAAA</ITGR>
    <SPE5> / ZS SPE5=</SPE5>
    <CSNO>40169300 / ZS CSNO=</CSNO>
    <UNMS>UN / ZS UNMS=P</UNMS>
    </ItemMaster>
</Record>
<Record>
    <ItemMaster><FLAG>DEFGH</FLAG>
    <CONO>700</CONO><WHLO>25H</WHLO>
    <STAT>40 / ZS STAT=20</STAT>
    <ITNO>P167135 / ZS ITNO=</ITNO>
    <SPE3> / ZS SPE3=</SPE3>
    <FRE3> / ZS FRE3=</FRE3>
    <UNNN>0 / ZS UNNN=</UNNN>
    <HAC1> / ZS HAC1=</HAC1>
    <HAC2> / ZS HAC2=</HAC2>
    <ITGR>AQGAAA / ZS ITGR=AQAAAA</ITGR>
    <SPE5> / ZS SPE5=</SPE5>
    <CSNO> / ZS CSNO=</CSNO>
    <UNMS>UN / ZS UNMS=P</UNMS>
    </ItemMaster>
</Record>
</ZBE14_OEMs_ItemUpdate_OUT>
```

[XML file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H0qVI.png)

Thanks to you guys :)

Comment: Can you add your XML as text in the question, rather than an image, as that way it makes it easier to copy into http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ to test. You don't need to add the whole XML. Just a sample with a couple of `Record` elements will do. Thanks!

Comment: Done ! Thank you Tim for your help, you're amazing !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `start-with` function in your template..

```
<xsl:template match="ZBE14_OEMs_ItemUpdate_OUT/Record/ItemMaster/FLAG">
    <xsl:if test="starts-with(normalize-space(), 'ABC')">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
            <xsl:value-of select="substring(normalize-space(), 1, 19)"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Alternatively, add a second template to ignore `FLAG` elements that don't start with "ABC"

```
<xsl:template match="ZBE14_OEMs_ItemUpdate_OUT/Record/ItemMaster/FLAG[not(starts-with(normalize-space(), 'ABC'))]" priority="2" />

<xsl:template match="ZBE14_OEMs_ItemUpdate_OUT/Record/ItemMaster/FLAG">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
        <xsl:value-of select="substring(normalize-space(), 1, 19)"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Note the priority is needed to avoid template conflicts, where two templates match the same element with the same priority.

EDIT: I think I may have misunderstood the question. If it is the case that your don't want to import `Record` element where `FLAG` does not start with "ABC" then try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ZBE14_OEMs_ItemUpdate_OUT/Record[not(starts-with(normalize-space(ItemMaster/FLAG), 'ABC'))]" />

<xsl:template match="ZBE14_OEMs_ItemUpdate_OUT/Record/ItemMaster/FLAG">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
        <xsl:value-of select="substring(normalize-space(), 1, 19)"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks ! I seems to work, but when I import to my ACCESS database, the model also import the recording that doesn't start with "ABC". What I would like, is that I only import the XML tthat actually start with "ABC". Thank you again.

Comment: I am afraid I don't know anything about importing into Microsoft Access. If the XSLT is giving you the output you expect, then I can't really give any more advice unfortunately.

Comment: I see. I'm not an expert at all at using XSL, but I saw some function like "choose". what do you think of ? Thank you again.

Comment: It might help if you edit your question to show a sample of your XML and the output you expect. Thanks!

Comment: @Hich - I have expanded my answer now.

Comment: That works perfectly, thank you Tim for your help ! :)